# Using JaCoCo/Eclemma in my Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jacoco

I am developing a plugin for Eclipse, and my plugin need the JaCoCo/Eclemma to analyse the coverage of a Java Project.

What is the best way to integrate the JaCoCo/Eclemma in my plugin?

In my plugin I have a button and when I click in this button, I want to call JaCoCo/Eclemma, something like this:

```
Coverage = JaCoCo.run( /* Projecto */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacoco architecture is quite different than other code coverage tools because it does not instrument the code, but uses a JRE agent to capture execution information.
I'm quite new to Jacoco and I'm not an Eclipse expert, but I guess your plugin must somehow:

1. create an execution
2. attach the jacoco agent to that execution
3. execute the tests
4. retrieve the jacoco output (I suggest the xml format)
5. parse the output and use it to augment the java source code view

If you are willing to accept a suggestion I like the way Jacoco reports coverage in its HTML report: green for covered lines, red for uncovered and yellow for partial branch coverage.

I would definitely install such plugin!

Comment: There is already Eclipse plugin based on JaCoCo that is named EclEmma and provides same highlighting. And JaCoCo anyway instruments bytecode, even if runs as an agent.